# How do I set SpringBoot so that it does not try and create a table in my MySQL DB when it starts up

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

My springboot trys to create a table that already exists in my mysql db

When I start springboot, it throws an exception

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table credential 

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'credential' already exists
```

Now I have an entity called credential

```
@Entity
@Table(name="credential")
public class CredentialEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

What I think is happening is that springboot sees the entity and try to create that table and throws an exception because the table already exists.

Is there a way to set something on the entity to stop springboot trying to create the table.

Comment: please share ur application.properties file ?

Comment: Disable hbm2ddl.

Answer (score 3):

JPA does have that feature to auto create tables, after scanning your entity classes. According to the [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html), the feature is controlled with the properties `spring.jpa.generate-ddl`(boolean) and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`(hibernate specific). Setting the first to false should stop table generation on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone In my application.properties file I had the following line
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update.

I removed this and now springboot starts up without trying to create a new table per entity.